# Group rows by contiguous date ranges for groups of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Consider some table `T`, ordered by `Col1, Col2, Date1, Date2`:

```
Col1    Col2    Date1         Date2          rate
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/5/2014      -90
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/6/2014      -55
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/7/2014      -90
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/10/2014     -90
```

I want to group the data so that changes are easily audited/reduce repetition, so I have

```
Col1    Col2    Date1         start_Date2    end_Date2      rate
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/5/2014      11/5/2014      -90
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/6/2014      11/6/2014      -55
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/7/2014      11/10/2014     -90
```

I can easily do that if I can get another column with the rows numbered as `1 2 3 3` (only important that numbers are distinct), and then `GROUP BY` that column.

My attempt at the query:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY rate) island
FROM T
ORDER BY Date2
```

doesn't give what I'm looking for:

```
Col1    Col2    Date1         Date2          rate     island
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/5/2014      -90      1
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/6/2014      -55      2
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/7/2014      -90      1
ABC     123     11/4/2014     11/10/2014     -90      1
```

I want the query to recognize the second group of `-90` values should be treated as a new group, since they appeared after a group with a different `rate`.

The [gaps-and-islands] SQL tag was pretty helpful, but I'm not quite able to figure out how to handle when the rate reverts back to a previous value. How should I modify my query?

Comment: You may be interested in [*this answer to, "Solving “Gaps and Islands” with row_number() and dense_rank()?*](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167069/2639)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify the groups by using the difference of `row_numbers()`.  Consecutive values will have a constant.

```
select col1, col2, date1, min(date2), max(date2), rate
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, date1 order by date2) -
              row_number() over (partition by col1, col2, date1, rate order by date2)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by col1, col2, date1, rate, grp
```

Comment: For an explanation to this you may be interested in [*this answer to, "Solving “Gaps and Islands” with row_number() and dense_rank()?*](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167069/2639)